# Is there a way to Connect your Google Reviews into a Django Website?

Tags: django, google-my-business-api, google-reviews

been looking for a tutorial whereby one can connect automatically the reviews they receive from Google My Business and add them as testimonials to a Django Website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the Google Business Profile APIs, it is possible to receive Pub/Sub notifications for [new or updated reviews](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/notifications/rest/v1/NotificationSetting#NotificationType). You would have to set up a Pub/Sub topic to which Google will send these notifications. A Pub/Sub subscription would then need to process these notifications and save the fetched review data to a database of choice.

The prerequisites for this are that you were granted access to the Google Business Profile APIs in the first place and that you have acess to those GBP locations.